# Why ist declaring and allocating a local iterator faster instead of using a global one?

Tags: c#, variables, memory, stack

I am a beginner in c#, I've programmed for a year, but only every now and then, so please be patient with me.

I've run a test setup with the following - very much basic - code:

```
namespace SpeedTest
{
    public class TestClass
    {
        internal struct testStruct {
            internal int iterator;
        }

        private testStruct _tS;
        private byte[] _bytes;


        public TestClass(string s)
        {
            _tS = new testStruct();
            _tS.iterator = 0;
            _bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(s);
        }

        public void runWithGlobalVar () 
        {
            while(_tS.iterator != _bytes.Length)
                _tS.iterator++;
        }

        public void runWithLocalVar() 
        {
            int i = 0;
            while (i != _bytes.Length)
                i++;
        }

        public void runWithTwoLocalVar() 
        {
            int i = 0;
            int y = _bytes.Length;
            while (i != y)
                i++;
        }
    }
}
```

If I speed-test this with fairly huge files (>15 MB, just for test purposes, wouldn't allocate that mutch into a byte array without some checks in practice), I observe the following behaviour:

- Fastest is runWithTwoLocalVar().
- Close, but second fastest is runWithLocalVar()
- Slowest is runWithGlobalVar(). It is significantly slower than the other two (Takes around 135% of the time needed for one of the other methods).

Can somebody explain to me the inner workings of this? What's happening with the memory, and why is runWithGlobalVar() taking that much longer?

Edit: Please keep in mind that this is a test setup and I see no sense in doing this like this in practice. It is just that I have seen this done in very complex code for various reasons, sometimes even in c# source code from Microsoft.

Comment: You need to read how `struct`s work and how they are different from`class`es

Comment: To get really comparable results you shouldn´t wrap the int's value in a struct, but simply use a **field** of type `int`.

Comment: @HimBromBeere Or at least make `internal struct testStruct` an `internal class testStruct`

Comment: It has to do with the Microprocessor.  There are segment registers that define memory areas.  Using Global variable you are using a different segment register.  Local variables are on the execution stack.  So it is taking more instructions cycles to access a memory location in a different segment than to use local variables in the same memory segment.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto But even than you have a level of indirection the other two tests don´t have. I doubt this would hurt performance much, though.

Comment: yes - i see no sense in doing this in practice, it's a test setup. I've seen this done in some other people's code though (for various reasons) - even in some of microsoft's source code...

Comment: @Simon Can you share some reference? It could be either bad code or necessary code, depending on the circumstances

Comment: eg. within the System.Xml namespace there is Microsofts Implementation of  the XmlReader (in XmlTextReaderImpl.cs). All buffering state data is stored in a struct and accessed rather quite frequently (if the buffer is read or refreshed).

Answer (score 0):

You need to check what `structs` do compared to `classes` in C#. ( [over here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/choosing-between-class-and-struct) for an intro and especially what is the difference between the stack and the heap).

Your `runWithTwoLocalVars` function uses ints that are stored right there, in the **function stack**: accessing them repeatedly doesn't cost much (we say there is no overhead).

On the other hand, your "global" version has to go and retrieve the data stored into the struct from where ever it is stored in memory: this has some overhead (it at least needs to "follow the pointer" designating the place where the struct instance resides in memory, both for `_ts` and `bytes`)

Comment: Exactly! But why is the struct not buffered in one of the CPU caches, since it is accessed all of the time and also is very small? Or does nothing on the heap gets ever cached into CPU cache?

Comment: Every piece of data gets into the CPU cache eventually.
Here, you are experiencing a lot of cache misses because of the way the data is laid out: you constantly have to switch from the stack of your `while` loop to the place where `_bytes` is stored, because C# has no way to know if you (or another thread) has modified the collection, so it queries the size again, which also has some overhead depending on the implementation.
Of course, the compiler can detect that kind of things and tries to optimize as much as possible. In your case, it can't since nothing is immutable here